# Highchart series mouseover

Tags: highcharts, mouseover, series

I´m trying to display a timeline using Highchart, my problem is that when you put the mouse over one element of the series, it highlight and shows the tool-tip of other element of the same series. What I´m doing wrong?

You can see a http://jsfiddle.net/ncdysafk/

```
var chart;
    var options = {

        chart: {
            events: {
                load: function(){
                    this.myTooltip = new Highcharts.Tooltip(this, this.options.tooltip);                    
                 }
             },
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'columnrange',
            inverted: true,
            zoomType: 'y'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Portes de hoy'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ["SERIE1","SERIE2","SERIE3"]
        },

        yAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            title: {
                text: 'Horas del día'
            }
        },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    stickyTracking: true,
                    events: {
                        click: function(evt) {
                            this.chart.myTooltip.refresh(evt.point, evt);
                        },
                        mouseOut: function() {
                            this.chart.myTooltip.hide();
                        }                       
                    }           
                },
                columnrange: {
                    grouping: false
                }
            },

        legend: {
            enabled: true
        },


        series: [{"name":"SERIE2","data":[{"x":1,"low":1425538800000,"high":1425543300000},{"x":1,"low":1425567600000,"high":1425571200000},{"x":1,"low":1425584000000,"high":1425589100000}]},{"name":"SERIE3","data":[{"x":2,"low":1425538800000,"high":1425543300000},{"x":2,"low":1425567600000,"high":1425571200000}]}]

    };

chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the manual tooltip handling?

Comment: If you have seen the jsfiddle, the "SERIE2" has three columns, but if you put the mouse over the column on the rigth, it shows the information of the center column. What I want to achive is to show the information of the column where you put the mouseover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is bug in 4.1.3/2.1.3 version of Highcharts/Highstock. Bug reported is [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3899). Already fixed, that means try `https://github.highcharts.com/highstock.js` and `https://github.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js` files from master branch. Working demo http://jsfiddle.net/ncdysafk/1/